# WordPress Landing Page that Differs in Design from Regular Pages

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Suppose you have a landing page that looks different than the main website--ie, different layout, different background, different header.

How can you use such a landing page on WordPress, since WordPress automatically formulates all pages to have the same layout, header, and footer?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the theme you use dictates the major design points of a site, but you can alter page templates to suit both design and data presentation. See https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development on how themes and page templates work. Create a new page template for your theme to change the design, and then select that page template for a page.

Or, if you want to keep the raw coding to a minimum, use a plugin to allow you to use two themes on the same site, and select which pages/posts use each theme: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-multiple-themes/

Answer (score 1):

I can't just add a comment yet in here, but this tutorial was perfect for me when I was needing to create sub pages based off of different templates. http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-create-a-custom-page-in-wordpress/

By using this you will be able to have a different layout, header, etc.